# Android: ViewPager section number returns invalid value

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I created a new project (Tabbed Activity).

This is default code for onCreateView

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format,getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));


        return rootView;
    }
```

but then I made some changes to the code:

```
        .
        .
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format,getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.section_format,getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return rootView;
        .
        .
```

But the Toast value is different from what textview displayed. So the question is, how can I get the exact(accurate) value of section number?

Edit 1: Toast displayed two times when activity first started.

Edit 2: Screenshot added.

[image]

Comment: What is your base class for Viewpager's adapter? Is it `PagerAdapter/FragmentPagerAdapter/FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? Also, in place of `Toast` you could try using `Log.d` statements..

Comment: Didn't sure what is my base class. Could be SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: i removed my earlier comment because the way i had written was not correct..The default behaviour for ViewPager is to "keep around" one page on either side of the page being viewed, and destroy the rest by default..the property is decided and could be altered by method  [`setOffscreenPageLimit `](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29).. you could set viewpager to show/instantiate only one fragment it is currently viewing by setting it as `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);`

Comment: Since setOffscreenPageLimit() is by default '1'.So, in that case your adjacent fragment's `oncreateview` gets called..Ex: When activity with viewpager is opened..your **first fragment's** as well as your **second fragment's** `oncreateview()` would be called resulting into Toast message coming up twice.. and when you swipe right(i.e. you come to 2nd fragment) your **third fragment's** `oncreateview()` gets called.. Hope that clears up the confusion..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,text from TextView might change faster. Whereas, the toast will continue showing until its time is up. It take approximately about 5s for the toast to change.  So, you might think the section is not the same.

My suggestion is to test using two TextViews.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Value is right when set to TextView, but I need to use the section number for further process.